# Raven Pro 1.6. - Date and time template issues for page sound

Tags: raven

I'm trying to read in .flac audio files to Raven Pro in the format "20200712T085500.flac" which is 08:55:00 on the 12th of July, 2020.

On the "Date and Time" tab on Raven Pro 1.6 when I select file name template, a standard template of "" comes up, but for "example start time" it says no match found.

Has anyone else encountered this? I know I need to change the template, but can't seem to find one that works.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

You can type directly in the 'File name template' box to specify your own template. You can then save that template for future use by clicking on the small down arrow to the right of the box and choosing 'Save as'.

I was able to generate a valid date for a file I renamed to match your format using the following string:

`<yy><ll><dd>T<hh><mm><ss>.`

The fact that I used a .wav file should not matter. Just end your formatting string with a period like in this screenshot:

[image]